# convert method on type to function of type

Tags: scala, methods, first-class-functions

Is it possible to convert a method on type T to a function of type T? For example, if I have

```
case class T {
  def foo(u : U) : Unit = ???
}
```

make it possible to pass foo as the argument somef in some way to

```
function bar(somef : (T, U) => Unit)
```

So far I have pulled it out of the type like so:

```
def foo_(t : T, u: U) = t.foo(u)
```

but that isn't all too DRY, or arguably quite WET even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: `bar(_.foo(_))` in your case. If Scala doesn't have enough information to infer types of arguments (e.g. if you had `bar[T1, T2](somef: (T1, T2) => Unit)`), you can use something like `(_: T).foo(_: U)` instead.